# Where is cck "number of values" data stored?

Tags: drupal-6, cck

I have a cck field that needs to allow a different number of values depending on the role of the currently logged in user.

I'd like to find where the "number of values" data is stored for a cck field so that it can be dynamically changed when the node edit form is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory, if you change the number of values you may lose any additional - if you allow 5, then change to 2 you lose the other 3.

Is this not more of a UI concern?  The CCK field itself can allow the max number of values that you want it to hold, and the widget that is used to allow these values to be entered / selected is customised based on the user role.

Changing the definition of an object based on the users role seems a bit excessive

Comment: I see your point.  It'd be better to allow unlimited values and then change the form widget from the UI level.  
Thanks for the clarification!